# Complex search window

Tags: search, dynamic-ui

Following a discussion here on my work, I like to call in the ideas of UX experts :-)

Thet starting point is a web page on which users can make a configuration of complex products. On the screen, there will be some buttons for search categories. Clicking on one button will open a window that will dynamically build the search options from a database. There are three levels:
- by default only the most used options will be on the popup
- more advanced users can ask more options & values
- and expert users can ask all possible options & values

So we come down to 2 versions, which one is the best, and what improvements can be made.

**Proposition 1: expand by clicking links**

Basic search:
[image]

Advanced search:
[image]

Expert search:
[image]

**Proposition 2: search catagories on top op window**

Basic search:
[image]

Advanced search:
[image]

Expert search:
[image]

Comment: Drag unsuspecting people in front of a screen and watch which one gives the best result.

Comment: are you going to allow multiple selection?

Comment: Slightly OT and a bit picky: In the first wireframe I'd use "less" instead of "back" as the opposite of "more", because "back" might make the user fear to be taken out of here to a previous context. 
In the second example I'd use "quick search" instead of "fast search". Hopefully all searchs will be _fast_ while only some will be _quick_ as in _quick and dirty_, i.e., easily started. Also, now you have 11 reputation!

Comment: @Igor-G In the admin website, the product manager can define all the functions and options. He may choose between: text, number, boolean, checkboxes or radiobuttons. Also, he can define on which search level the function should appear: null, 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: @JuanLanus Thank you for this input. I have modified the labels. And also thank you for the upvotes, I have added the images inline.

Comment: Is this product for consumers? If not, popup and implicitly assuming users will know in what group they are (default, advanced, expert) sounds strange. You might better want to go with some sort of questionaire/wizard or with a default list and then allow for filtering.

Comment: @greenforest This window will be for dealers, selling our products. When they open the window, basic search will be the first presented. It could be that the product manager can define some default options. Users with a basic understanding will only need the first level of functions, experts can tweak the search by requesting all functions. A questionnaire or wizard is not going to be the best because it is hard make it dynamic and needs more clicks when a quick selection is required. Of course, users will get a basic training.

Comment: There is [similar question] (http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28826/ui-design-for-multiple-attribute-based-filtering/29023#29023) that might interest you. Searching and filtering the results on [Cars.com](http://www.cars.com/for-sale/advancedsearch.action) is an example of the type of search you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use drop down menus? The user might be confused or not notice "expert"/"novice" settings.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0yZwQ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I can give the product manager an extra option to make it a dropdownlist. But anyway, the point is: what is the best design for the users, clicking on links on the bottom of the page or on buttons on top of the page to extend search possibilities.

Comment: The less confusing it is the better. The way I see it, also based on [lukew web form design](http://www.lukew.com/resources/web_form_design.asp)
 , long forms scare users and the easier they look the bigger chance that the user would fill it out.

Comment: if the question is only about the links, I would suggest you putting them at the top, then the user would see the options before starting to fill-out the form, but there is a down side to this solution the users might skip the options. Personally I don't like the idea of your form. So I would suggest you use the drop down menus for this.

Comment: adding buttons at the bottom isn't a good idea because the 1st thing user will try to get out of his way is the form so the user might not realise that there are extra options are available. I believe the user will be hesitant of pressing the buttons after filling out the form, they might be afraid of the form loosing all the data, so they would have to fill out the form again (happened to me few times, never used that website again).